# XCode is missing "Near Field Communication Tag Reading" capability

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nfc, core-nfc

I am trying to use the NFC capabilities with swift, and the apple docs say to enable the aforementioned "Near Field Communication Tag Reading" capability, but when I look in the capabilities menu, it is not there. Does anybody know what the issue is here? I believe I have a fairly recent version of xcode. I saw someone else say that it was because I needed to purchase the apple developer license, and so I did. Do I need to do something to get xcode to recognize that I have the developer license other than restart xcode?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the capability in Xcode first. And Same capability you need to enable for the app bundle id in the Apple Developer portal -> Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> Identifiers - > Select your app -> Enable NFC Tag Reading -> Save.

[image: NFC Capability in Xcode]

Next, edit your app profile in the "Profiles" section and download the updated provisioning profile and install it. This will set up your NFC in Xcode.

*Note: If you have recently added an account in Xcode make sure you have development certificates installed in your system.*

[image: Add NFC Reading capability in app in developer portal]

Comment: Okay, I see it now!

Comment: Do I need a provisioning profile to use the app on my device? Because I've been able to get it to run on my own device before, do things change now that I've enabled NFC?

Comment: yes previously you might sign in with a personal account and now you have enrolled with apple so you need the provisioning to install it. Your device UDID should be added to that profile.